# Node.js Discord Bot : TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

I'm still in the process of learning discord.js but I'm struggling with passing a discord message send function from one .js file to another. Below I stripped out all the complex stuff, and just left it with the barebones, in hopes someone can understand it, and provide guidance!
The idea is, (eventually) when there is a new update on `'true'`, it sends the message 'hello world' to all discord servers. Right now for debug purposes I have it using my developer discord channel. 
Everything is ran via `nf run npm start`

**Hello.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const disconfig = require("./config/default.json");

// new function
function message(message) {
     const messageInfoEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .addField('Hey:')
        .addField('Testing: ')
       .addField('NoWorries: ')

    return messageInfoEmbed
}

// Function OnUpdate() {
// if (updatedcontent === true) {


exports.wrapper = async(client, message) => {
client.channels.get("519344197078220804").send(message(message));

}
//}
//}
```

**Server.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const disconfig = require("./config/default.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`);
var sayHello = require('./hello');
sayHello.wrapper(); // "Hello World! Message via Discord"
});
client.on("message", async(message) => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.content.indexOf(disconfig.prefix) !== 0) return;
        const args = 
          message.content.slice(disconfig.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (command === "test?") {


        }
}
client.login(disconfig.token);
```

**error**

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Object.exports.wrapper (X:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\app\hello.js:20:8)`

Comment: Using the same name for a function and its parameter is a recipe for error

Comment: thats a great callout! Thx.. Still doesn't resolve the initial issue, but super helpful for me to remember

Comment: On what line exactly do you get the error?

Comment: hi @T.Dirks I went and added error at the bottom. Basically channels is undefined from hello.js and i can't figure out why when i run start that is server.js

Comment: Your parameter the wrapper function (client) shadows the outer var. Then when you call it from the other file since you don't pass any args `client` is undefined in the function.

Comment: @JaredSmith if possible could you provide an example? A bit unclear about what you mean with wrapper shadowing and putting a second args .

Comment: `exports.wrapper = async(client, message) => {` means that the function expects to have `client` passed in. That parameter declaration shadows the `client` defined at the top of the file (meaning it's invisible inside the function). So when you call it in the other file like so `sayHello.wrapper();` with **no** arguments, kaboom.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't believe I can give you the 'accepted answer' checkbox b/c you only made a comment. Happy to do so

Comment: @JaredSmith just tagging you in case you didn't see my response! Thanks again!

Comment: @paintball247 posted an answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript (and pretty much every other programming language) variable declarations in inner scopes shadow (think override) declarations with the same names in an outer scope:

```
var foo = 3;
var bar = 5;
var f = (foo) => {
  var bar = 1;
  return [foo, bar];
};

var results = f(0);
console.log(results); // [0, 1]
```

N.B. you don't get `[3, 5]`. So in your code:

```
exports.wrapper = async(client, message) => {
```

means that the function expects to have client passed in. That parameter declaration shadows the client defined at the top of the file (meaning it's invisible inside the function). So when you call it in the other file like so

```
sayHello.wrapper();
```

with no arguments, kaboom.

Answer (score 1):

Use `message.guild` instead. It should work.